# Any difference in " 'value' == typeof X " VS " typeof X == 'value' "

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference (compiler/interpreter/juju wise, etc) between the two versions of checking the result of the typeof operator?

I am asking because I see the first version a lot of times, as if it followed a concept, while version two is way more readable and better describes my intention: primarily I am interested in the type of a variable and not a string being equal with something.

UPDATE:
while it's not part of the original question it worth noting that x == y is never a good practice when you are about to check equality. One should always use the === operator for that.

Comment: Looks like something you could trial yourself with a couple of big loops... Be surprised if there is much difference in these.

Comment: Please use === instead, == is not really an equality operation (it's not transitive for example so a==b and b==c does not imply a==c)

If you use === there is no difference between a===b and b===a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

There is no difference in terms of functionality but it seems that in JavaScript, you get an error in either way (which is good, thanks to JS):

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

So it seems to be just a habit of developers from other programming languages. For example in PHP if you did:

```
if ($var = 'foo')
```

PHP will silently assign `foo` as value to `$var` but with following:

```
if ('foo' = $var)
```

It will throw an error.

---

> I am asking because I see the first version a lot of times

There is no difference in what they do. However first version will throw an error if you happen to write:

```
'value' = typeof X
```

Notice `=` instead of `==` or `===`

This is generally good practice, people from *other languages* have habit of doing it that way in JavaScript also.

Comment: second version throws the same error, you can't assign a value to a function or operator call. I get (in v8) "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment " for typeof {} = 5

Comment: yeah, this is a typo we do a lot of times.

Comment: In php I use this `if(value==$var)` to avoid mistakes because it'll throw an error if I use `=` instead of `==`, so I can be aware of typos. So I think in javascript it could be used for the same reason to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no difference, as the equivalence operation will return the same thing, regardless of which way round it is.

Comment: == is not an equivalence operator, since equivalence relation requires reflexivity (which is broken by NaN == NaN) and transitivity (a==b and b==c does not imply a==c using unstrict equality)